# How to open a Project from Pycharm using the same env created from Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I having been working a project on Visual Studio Code the whole time and now I am trying to switch to Pycharm and continue on the same project.

I have created for a project a virtual environment in project called env which when I activate it in Pycharm it works except that when I try to run code it shows the following error:

```
bash: python: command not found
```

Worth to mention that I am working on a Django project and the I am trying the run the server after activating the env

Also I tried to configure Python but it is showing nothing
[image]

What should I do to proceed without having to download all packages from scratch?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is that python installation in the PATH?

edit (sorry for the lack of info): hit 'Windows Key + R', and type 'sysdm.cpl', then click 'enter'. Select the advanced tab at the top, and click 'Environment Variables'. Under System variables, find the variable with the name 'Path' and click Edit. Go to the end of the Variable Value field and type ';C:\Python39'. Now, close out of all of the boxes and open the command prompt and type 'python --version'. It will show your current python version if you successfully added python to the PATH.

Comment: I don't understand your question could you please clarify?

Comment: I have reached to the Edit Environment Variable am I supposed to click new and type 'C:\Python39' ?

Comment: No, type   ;C:\Python39   with the semicolon